# Convert generator (iterator) to django queryset

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have Django model property `__iter__` which returns generator (iterator), now further I want to convert the resulted iterator to queryset, which allows me to do further filtering on the resulting queryset.

```
car = Car.objects.get(id=45)
# __iter__ returns Car objects
cars = car.__iter__()
cars.filter(name='abc') ?
```

The above will throw error, because I cannot filter generator(iterator).

Also I dont want to convert the generator(iterator) to list of id's, that I can use in `Car.objects.filter()`

Any ideas on how to solve the above problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if your `__iter__` method returns a generator, it is not possible to perform further queryset methods on it.

One option is to return ids and use a `id__in` filter, but you've already said you don't want to do that.

Another option is to do the additional filtering in Python instead of SQL.

```
car = Car.objects.get(id=45)
# __iter__ returns Car objects
cars = car.__iter__()
cars = [c for c in cars in c.name='abc']
```

Without knowing what `__iter__` does, I can't offer any other suggestions.